# create a control assigner menu for games

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to build a windows application using WinForms and C#, in one of the forms i want the user to be able to assign keys for each movement (i.e. left , right , up ,down motion etc.). That is something similar to

[image]

On the left hand side column the moves will be listed and the user should be able to assign a key for every move. I am very new to windows forms and am unable to figure out what control to use for the left hand side things, i tried using buttons with KeyDown event but in this the event does not trigger for enter/return key, for rest of the keys it works fine. So what control along with what event should be used so that the user can assign any key of his choice for any motion/control.

EDIT: this was the initial code.

```
namespace ControllerWinServe
{


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    static string[] array = new string[6]; 
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button_d_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button_u_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" + e.KeyCode.ToString() + "' pressed.");
    }

    private void button_d_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: b2 '" +e.KeyCode.ToString() + "'pressed.");
    }
}
}
```

AFTER Trying to use user17753 's suggestion.

```
namespace ControllerWinServe
{
  public class EnterTextBox : TextBox
 {
  protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys key)
  {
    if (key == Keys.Enter)
        return true;
    return base.IsInputKey(key);
 }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    static string[] array = new string[6]; 
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button_d_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button_u_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: '" + e.KeyCode.ToString() + "' pressed.");
    }

    private void button_d_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form.KeyPress: b2 '" +e.KeyCode.ToString() + "'pressed.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about hitting enter in a `TextBox` it isn't triggered by default.  You can create a new one called for example `EnterTextBox` that is derived from `TextBox` that overrides `IsInputKey` to allow enter to trigger the event.

One such implementation could be:

```
public class EnterTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys key)
    {
        if (key == Keys.Enter)
            return true;
        return base.IsInputKey(key);
    }
}
```

With this class in your project's namespace you'll be able to add `EnterTextBox` from the Toolbox under your project's namespace category.

Then you can add a method that is triggered by the `KeyDown` event on the `EnterTextBox` such as this:

```
    private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            //stuff to do after enter is pressed
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried using the code provided by you, but after using the code the designer view simply goes off and i am unable to add any tools using drag and drop method. Could you please have a look at the code. Thanks for answering.